# Largest value of $n$ such that the complementary set of any $n$-element subset contains at least two elements that are coprime

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

What is the largest value of $n$ such that the complementary set of any subset with $n$ elements of {1, 2, ..., 1989} contains at least two elements that are coprime? I am looking for the most general solution. For the sake of context: any mathematical methods can be used to provide a solution to the problem, so long as the solution is the most general.

Comment: $n=994$. If $S\subseteq\{1,\dots,1989\}$ and $|S|=994$ then the complementary set either contains two consecutive numbers or else it contains all the odd numbers, either way it contains two coprime numbers. If $n\ge995$, then an $n$-element subset could contain all of the odd numbers from $1$ to $1989$ so the complement contains only even numbers..

Comment: Ok. I see. Thank you.

Comment: The phrase "the solution is the most general" suggests to me that you have in mind a family of problems, not just the single instance "with $n$ elements in $\{1,\ldots,1989\}$".  Perhaps you can clarify what "most general" requires, or state the general problem with greater clarity.

Comment: Yes. I did have in mind a family of problems, but I wasn't quite sure how to clarify what the family of problems was, so I simply changed the problem to give a specific instance. The solution below really captures the family of problems I was trying to address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be a finite set of consecutive integers, $|S|\ge2$. Let $D=\{x\in S:x\text{ is odd}\}$ and $E=\{x\in S:x\text{ is even}\}$.

**Claim.** $|D|-1$ is the largest number $n\le|S|$ such that, for any $n$-element set $X\subseteq S$, the complementary set $S\setminus X$ contains two coprime elements.

**I,** Suppose $n=|D|-1$. Consider any set $X\subseteq S$ with $|X|=n=|D|-1$, and let $Y=S\setminus X$, so that $|Y|=|E|+1\ge2$. It is easy to see that $Y$ contains two consecutive integers unless $Y=D$. In either case, $Y$ contains two coprime elements; either two consecutive integers or else two consecutive odd numbers.

**II.** Suppose $|D|\le n\le|S|$. Then there is an $n$-element set $X$ such that $D\subseteq X\subseteq S$. Since all elements of $S\setminus X$ are even numbers, no two of them are coprime.